# C# Binding Collection + Animation

Tags: c#, binding, uwp

I have a List Source and bind it with a XAML control.
Please think like this. I made it with "CustomControl".

1. List A ( String "A" + animation )
2. List B ( String "B" + animation )
3. List C ( String "C" + animation )

[image]

Now, I can see 3 item on UI.and Each UI has a repeated animation.
Example : Change XY size to 1.0 , 2.0 and 1.0 ( same size ) and repeat it forever.

**My problem.**

If I update the list with PropertyChanged ,
Repeated animation change to strange. Because When I update one of list,
PropertyChanged is called. and Animation forced start from beginning. it is not beautiful repeat... : (

Is there any idea ?

**My idea.**

Now, I have a source property for the list. Example :

```
ObservableCollection<DerMeter> _derSource = new ObservableCollection<DerMeter>();
public ObservableCollection<DerMeter> DerSource
    {
        get { return _derSource; }
        set
        {
            this.Set(ref _derSource, value); // = PropertyChanged
        }
    }
```

and I modify "_derSource" first and Insert it to Property.

```
private void updateSource()
{
                //Do something..
                DerSource = _derSource;
}
```

and it call PeopertyChanged. and C# will make New UI from updated list.
this mean, Animation will be reset and start from beginning.

if it is NOT list, C# will not make new UI.

Comment: you mean storyboard animation ?

Comment: It would be much better if have put some example code with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Probably what you can try is, turn off the PropertyChanged event while updating the list and turn on once the update is done.

```
YourModel.PropertyChanged -= YourModel_PropertyChanged;

// Update the list.

YourModel.PropertyChanged += YourModel_PropertyChanged;
```

Comment: I update some code... but I can not upload my code. because It is connected with a device. Without device, it does not work...